# windows phone listbox stretch Item template items with ItemPanel Orientation Horizontally aligned

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am creating a ListBox in Windows Phone application such that items are aligned horizontally. I want that if there are 5 items then they should occupy the space equally if there are 2 items in collection there should be aligned accordingly occupying Totalwidth/2 space. How can i achieve this below is code that i have written:

```
   <ListBox x:Name="CarSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding listData}" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                     Background="White" 
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SelectorContainerStyle}" 
                     Style="{StaticResource lstbxSelectorStyle}"
                     >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                           <Grid>
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <control:GridItemPanelBehavior />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            >
                            <Image  Height="56"
                            Width="56"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Source="{Binding id}" />
                            </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Behavior:

```
protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated;
        }

        void AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Grid gridItemPanel = AssociatedObject as Grid;

            var childCount = gridItemPanel.Children.Count;

            // add the required number of column definitions
            for (int row = 0; row < childCount; row++)
            {
                gridItemPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            }

            // set the column property for each chid
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
            {
                var child = gridItemPanel.Children[i] as FrameworkElement;
                Grid.SetColumn(child, i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: After some research I found a solution where in WPF application we can use dynamic grid in Item Panel. How can I achieve the same in Windows Phone as shown in this link http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html

Comment: To achieve this I have created a behaviour that i am adding in ItemPanel Grid of the Listbox. And setting the grid columns and its width as star. Plus settings items column in Layout update but now the problem is that it is going into an no ending layout update loop as I am updating the layout in layout update. I have updated the code. Please let me know about the solution